# Simple Logic or Regex Expresssion for a string

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi I've a string like the following -

```
name,number,address(line1,city),status,contact(id,phone(number,type),email(id),type),closedate
```

I need to output the following -

```
name,number,address.line1,address.city,status,contact.id,contact.phone.number,contact.phone.type,contact.email.id,contact.type,closedate
```

Is it possible to do it using regex in java. Logic I have thought of is using string manipulation (with substring,recursion etc). Is there a simple way of achieving this? I would prefer a regular expression which works in java. Other suggestions are also welcome.
To give you a context 
The string above is coming as query parameter, I have to find out what all columns I need to select based on that. so all these individual items in the output will have a respective column name in property file.

Thanks
Pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ;
        String input ="name,number,address(line1,test(city)),status,contact(id,phone(number,type),email(id),type),closedate";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split(","))); // We need a list for the iterator (or ArrayIterator)
        List<String> result = new Main().parse(list);
        System.out.println(String.join(",", result));
    }

    private List<String> parse(List<String> inputString){
        Iterator<String> it = inputString.iterator();
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String word = it.next();
            if(! word.contains("(")){
                result.add(word);
            } else { // if we come across a "(", start the recursion and parse it till we find the matching ")"
                result.addAll(buildDistributedString(it, word,""));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /*
    * recursivly parse the string
     * @param startword The first word of it (containing the new prefix, the ( and the first word of this prefic
     * @param prefix Concatenation of previous prefixes in the recursion
     */
    private List<String> buildDistributedString(Iterator<String> it, String startword,String prefix){

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] splitted = startword.split("\\(");
        prefix += splitted[0]+".";

        if(splitted[1].contains(")")){ //if the '(' is immediately matches, return only this one item
            result.add(prefix+splitted[1].substring(0,splitted[1].length()-1));
            return result;
        } else {
            result.add(prefix+splitted[1]);
        }

        while(it.hasNext()){
            String word = it.next();
            if( word.contains("(")){ // go deeper in the recursion
                List<String> stringList = buildDistributedString(it, word, prefix);
                if(stringList.get(stringList.size()-1).contains(")")){
                    // if multiple ")"'s were found in the same word, go up multiple recursion levels
                    String lastString = stringList.remove(stringList.size()-1);
                    stringList.add(lastString.substring(0,lastString.length() -1));
                    result.addAll(stringList);
                    break;
                }
                result.addAll(stringList);
            } else if(word.contains(")")) { // end this recursion level
                result.add(prefix + word.substring(0,word.length()-1)); // ")" is always the last char
                break;
            } else {
                result.add(prefix+word);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I wrote a quick parser for this. There probably are some improvements possible, but this should give you an idea. It was just meant to get a working version asap.

Comment: you should mention that this only works using java 8

Comment: Not sure, but I think it would also work with java 7. Even if not, I dont think it would be hard to rewrite the parts that aren't.

Comment: `String.join()` was only introduced in java 8, and OP (or anybody else) might not know about it and assume your code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since nested parentheses appear in your string, regular expressions can't do the job. The explanation why is complicated, requiring knowledge in context free grammars. See [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

I've heard this kind of parsing can be done through callbacks, but I believe it doesn't exist in Java.

Parser generators like JavaCC would do the job, but that's a *huge* overkill for the task you are describing.

I recommend you to look into `java.util.Scanner`, and you recursively call the parse method whether you see a left paren.